# Is there a script/code for Google Forms to pull data from a spreadsheet upon completion?

Tags: google-apps-script

Looking to have someone fill a simple Google form, and then automatically give them a key from a spreadsheet. Then, upon the next completion of the form, it pulls from the next cell in the sheet. So each completion receives a new data point until it runs out.

Comment: Welcome. Please add a brief description of your search/research efforts. Questions including a brief description of what was tried and description of where the asker got stuck are usually well received. Ref. [tour] and [ask].

Answer (score -1):

That is totally doable though gScript. Here are the steps to get to where you wanna go:

1. Create your form
2. Make sure that the output is going to a gSheet where your keys also live
3. Create an onSubmit function so that your function (called onSubmit) is ran when a user submits to your form

Assuming your keys are all in a single column on one page, you could use MailApp to send them an email, and use

`sheetName.getRange(sheetName.getLastRow(), 1).getValue()`

to get the key you want to send, and after successfully emailing it to them, just clear the value like so:

`sheetName.getRange(sheetName.getLastRow(), 1).clear()`

Hopefully that helps out!

Comment: Not all questions should be answered. Please checkout [answer].